# Erro ao enviar email usando JavaMail

Tags: java

Alguém poderia me ajudar a corrigir esse erro? Não consigo enviar o email para a caixa de entrada.

Segue o código abaixo:

```
@Service
public class EnvioEmailServicoImpl implements EnvioEmailServico {

    @Override
    public void enviarEmail(String id){

        String destinatarioEmail = null;    

        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", "xxxxxx.xxxxxxxx.org.br");//
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "25");//465
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "false");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "25");      

        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, new javax.mail.Authenticator() {

            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                //return new PasswordAuthentication("", "");
                return null;
            }
        });
        session.setDebug(true); 

        FabricaConexao fabricaConexao = new FabricaConexao();

        Connection connection = fabricaConexao.getConexao();

        String sql = "select fun_email from tbl_funcionario where fun_codigo = ?";

        try {
            PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
            statement.setString(1, id);
            ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery();

            while (resultSet.next()) {
                Funcionario fun = new Funcionario();
                fun.setEmail(resultSet.getString("fun_email"));
                destinatarioEmail = fun.getEmail();
            }
        } catch (SQLException sE) {
            FacesUtil.adicionaMensagemErro("Erro no SQL: " + sE);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            FacesUtil.adicionaMensagemErro("Erro :" + ex);
        }       

        String remetente = "xxxxx.xxxxxxxx@xxxxxxx.org.br";//email do administrador
        String destinatario =  destinatarioEmail;//email do funcionário que solicitou nova senha    

        try {
            Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(remetente));// Remetente
            Address[] toUser = InternetAddress.parse(destinatario);// Destinatarios
            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, toUser);
            message.setSubject("Gerar senha");// assunto
            message.setText("Segue abaixo link para realizar a troca de sua senha!!");
            message.setContent("Você solicitou alterar sua Senha de acesso,</br> Para criar nova senha, clique no link abaixo: <br/>"+"<html><a href=\"localhost:8080/sgc/pages/gerarSenha.xhtml?id="+id+"\">"
                    + "http://localhost:8080/sgc/pages/gerarSenha.xhtml </a></html>", "text/html");
            Transport.send(message);    

        } catch (Exception e) {
            FacesUtil.adicionaMensagemErro("Erro ao tentar enviar email: "+ e);
        }
    }
    }
```

Erro do catch:

> Erro ao tentar enviar email: com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException:
>   Couldn't connect to host, port: xxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxx.org.br, 25; timeout
>   -1; nested exception is: java.net.SocketException: Network is unreachable: connect

Erro do debug do JavaMail:

> DEBUG: setDebug: JavaMail version 1.5.5 DEBUG: getProvider() returning
>   javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Oracle]
>   DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth false DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect
>   to host "xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxx.org.br", port 25, isSSL false

Answer (score 1):

Acho que isso é problema de porta do SMTP, se me lembro bem as operadoras bloquearam a porta 25 em 2012 (me corrijam se eu estiver errado).

Tenta a porta 587

```
props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "587");
```

Answer (score 0):

A propriedade `mail.smtp.ssl.trust` pode ser usada para dizer explicitamente que deve confiar no certificado do smtp host.

No seu caso:

```
props.put("mail.smtp.ssl.trust", "xxxxxxx.xxxxxxx.org.br");
```

Traduzido da documentação do [JavaMail](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/com/sun/mail/smtp/package-summary.html):

> mail.smtp.ssl.trust   - Se setado, e o *socket factory* não for especificado, habilita o uso do *MailSSLSocketFactory*. Se setado "*", todos os *hosts* serão confiáveis. Se setado com uma lista de *hosts* separados por espaço em branco, esse *hosts* serão confiáveis. Caso contrário, o certificado é passa a ser confiável à partir do que o servidor apresenta.

Comment: Alterei a configuração e deixei dessa forma... porém dá erro, poderia verificar o porque por favor? Vou comentar o código novamente,

Comment: A mesma exceção foi lançada?

Comment: Na outra resposta que você postou, o problema parece estar no seu servidor smtp, verifique se ele está UP.

Comment: O que acontece é que o outro ele tinha dado vários erros, então troquei o código, agora ele da esse erro:

javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Oracle] DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth false DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxx.org.br", port 25, isSSL false

aí ele cai no catch e apresenta a msg:

com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to host, port: xxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxx.org.br, 25; timeout -1; nested exception is: java.net.SocketException: Network is unreachable: connect

Comment: Verifique se o nome do seu host smtp está correto, se ele está up. Tente fazer um ping.

Comment: Já fiz um ping no SMTP que estou usando, e ele está up, ta respondendo normalmente